# passing a model to the next controller from view

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I have a form with few inputs, `name`, `email`, `message` and some `checkboxes`. I've created a model for these inputs and set all the validations i require.

But now I also want to pass my model (i.e. from `@model MyModel`) or rather some object property of my model together with those inputs.

Is populating a `VewBag/viewData` with my model a way to go?

```
@{
      ViewBag.MyModel = Model;
      // or ViewBag.ThatProperty = Model.ThatProperty
}
```

or do i still have a better way up my sleeve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ViewBag** and **ViewData** persist in one trip from server to client, and not the other way around.

There is no way to pass an object from the view to the controller. If it's a database object, you can pass the object Id using one of the two methods described below, then query the DB on post.

If you have no other way, you can encode the object as a JSON string (using the Newtonsoft package, for example) and pass it also using one of the two methods described below, but this isn't the best option.

To pass a property from the View to the Controller, you have two options:

- Url Parameter
- Hidden field

**Url Parameter**

```
<form ... asp-route-ThatProperty="@Model.ThatProperty">
...
</form>
```

**Form Field**

```
<form>
<input type="hidden" name="ThatProperty" value="@Model.ThatProperty" />
</form>
```

**Controller Action**

If 'ThatProperty' doesn't exist on your model, receive it as an extra parameter.

```
public IActionResult MyAction (MyModel model, string ThatProperty)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: the problem is `ThatProperty` is an object not a simple property like `int` or `string`

Comment: There is no way to pass an object from the View to the controller. If it's a database object, then you can pass the Id of the object and query the database on form post.

Comment: I see. Thank you. I will just extract relevant properties.